# Число из массива в переменную Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Пытаюсь из mysql вывести максимальное значение. Пишу код.

```
SELECT MAX(count) AS maxcount FROM table1
```

вижу это максимальное значение, обращаюсь через php

```
$maxcount = $mysqli->query('SELECT MAX(count) AS maxcount FROM table1');
```

Естественно, так как там массив, с одним числом, мне не дает просто так записать его в переменную, и выводит ошибку.

```
Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string
```

Как можно это единственное значение оттуда внести в переменную?
Спасибо

Comment: `fetch` теперь не нужен что ли?

Comment: *так как там массив* Там вообще-то объект, а не массив. Типа `mysqli_result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы пытаетесь объект mysqli result в строку перевести, ибо забыли прочитать данные из результата (т.е. сделать `fetch`)

```
$res = $mysqli->query('SELECT MAX(count) AS maxcount FROM table1');
if($res){
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $maxCount = $row['maxcount'] ;
}
```